# SQL Count distinct number of rows in table in GBQ

Tags: sql, count, google-bigquery

I'd like to count the number of distinct rows in a table. I know that I can do that using groupby or by naming all the columns one by one, but would like to just do:

```
select count(distinct *) from my_table
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Does the table have a primary key?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `to_json_string()`:

```
select count(distinct to_json_string(t))
from t;
```

Comment: Thank you Gordon! I love this syntax!

Answer (score 3):

Do `SELECT DISTINCT` in a *derived table* (the subquery), then count the number of rows returned.

```
select count(*) from
(select distinct * from my_table) dt
```

(Doesn't your table have any primary key?)

Answer (score 1):

Below more options for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
select count(distinct format('%t', t))
from `project.dataset.table` t
```

depends on your use case - approximate count can be even more optimal option

```
select approx_count_distinct(format('%t', t))
from `project.dataset.table` t
```

> APPROX_COUNT_DISTINCT - returns the approximate result for COUNT(DISTINCT expression). The value returned is a statistical estimate—not necessarily the actual value. This function is less accurate than COUNT(DISTINCT expression), but **performs better on huge input**.

Comment: Thank you Mikhail! And for the addition of the approx_count_distinct for larger tables.

Answer (score 0):

The use of `count(distinct *)` is not permitted.

Alternatively you could explicitly name the columns (what defines uniqueness).